# Webdriver + PhantomJS just hangs in there

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm using Selenium Webdriver (in Python) to automate the downloading of thousands of files from a certain website (that can't be webscraped by conventional means like urllib, httplib, etc). My script works perfectly with Firefox, but I don't need to see magic happening, so I'm trying to use PhantomJS. It works almost all the way down, except when it tries to click a certain button in order to close a window. Here's the command at which the script gets stuck:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Close Window\"]").click()
```

It just hangs in there, nothing happens.

PhantomJS is faster than Firefox (since there are no visuals), so I thought the problem might be related to the 'Close Window' button not being clickable soon enough. Hence I tried using an explicit wait:

```
element = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[alt=\"Close Window\"]")))
print "done with waiting"
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Close Window\"]").click()
```

Doesn't work: the wait ends pretty quickly (the "done with waiting" message appears after a second or so), but then the code hangs again. I've also tried using an implicit wait, but that didn't work either.

So, I'm at a loss. The same script runs like a charm when I use Firefox, so why doesn't the it work with PhantomJS?

I don't know if this helps, but here is the page source:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/88729961@N00/9512669916/sizes/l/in/photostream/

I don't know if this helps either, but when I break the execution w/ Crtl-C, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myscript.py", line 361, in <module>
    myfunction(some_argument, some_other_argument)
  File "myscript.py", line 277, in myfunction
    browser.find_element_by_css_selector("img[alt=\"Close Window\"]").click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 54, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 228, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 163, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 349, in execute
    return self._request(url, method=command_info[0], data=data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.33.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 396, in _request
    response = opener.open(request)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 365, in _read_status
    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline
    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I'm new to programming and I can't make sense of this output (I don't even know what a "socket" is). But maybe some of you can point me in the right direction? A quick fix might be too much to ask, but maybe a hint as to what could be going on?

(Mac OS X 10.6.8, Python 2.7.5, Selenium 2.33, PhantomJS 1.9.1)

Comment: What happen if you run this line? : browser.execute_script("closeWindow(false, '/lnacui2api/cart/displayCart.do', 'false');");

Comment: I ended up resorting to the quick and dirty `browser.close()` fix. Now I won't have access to the code until Monday, but then I'll try your suggestion and see what output I get.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, the main solution to this question might have something to do with visibility of the image on screen. You may want to execute javascript such as "window.scrollTo(0, [somewhere that image should be visible]);", then try finding that element again.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following line of code in your script, solves the question.

```
browser.execute_script("closeWindow(false, '/lnacui2api/cart/displayCart.do', 'false');");
```